# Can I use charger of Acer Veriton L410 for Acer Aspire laptops?

Tags: acer-aspire, charger, acer-veriton

Can I use charger of Acer Veriton L410 for Acer Aspire 3620 laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO although they share the same connector

I tried and it does not work